# Disable spring security authentication in specific method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security 4 on my app. In my app I have registration page, I want to exclude this page from checking authentication.
How can I exclude specific controller method from being authenticated?

my security config:

```
 http.antMatcher("/test")
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/",       "/scripts/**",
                    "/bower_components/**", "/styles/**", "/views/**",
                    "/login", "/api/user/*").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registration")
public ResponseEntity<RestUser> registration(
        @RequestBody RestUser restuser, Principal p) throws Exception {
```

}

Comment: show us your controller and spring security config .. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add the registration URL to the permit all in your config. I have added `/registration` to your spring security config

```
http.antMatcher("/test")
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/",       "/scripts/**",
                    "/bower_components/**", "/styles/**", "/views/**",
                    "/login", "/api/user/**","/registration").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

### Update

Please change  `/api/user/*` to `/api/user/**`. It should work.

Comment: the "/registration" is already part of "/api/user/*" and this still want me to authenticate with browser default authentication dialog.

Comment: How complete path to registration page looks like?

Comment: /api/user/registration